# Usage of "high weight" of in representation theory

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

In the [1999 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9807160.pdf) of Knutson and Tao, they begin by introducing the following question:

> A very old and fundamental question about the representation theory of
> $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the following:
> For which triples of dominant weights $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ does the
> tensor product $V_\lambda \otimes V_\mu \otimes V_\nu$ of the
> irreducible representations with those **high weights** contain a
> $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$-invariant vector?

Here they use the word "high weights" which I've never heard of. I think it should be "highest weights", but wonder if anyone has seen the usage of expression like "high weight representation" or "representation with high weight $\lambda$".